# sonar-runner is not parsing files in the cpp example

Tags: debian, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have a sonarqube 5.4 server running, where I installed the [cpp plugin](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/languages/cpp/) the latest version (which is now 3.10). I also installed [the builder](http://sonarsource.bintray.com/CommercialDistribution/sonar-cpp-plugin/build-wrapper-3.10.zip) and the [sonar-runner](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/sonar/runner/sonar-runner-dist/2.4/sonar-runner-dist-2.4.zip).

I downloaded the [cpp exaple](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples) and executed the sonar-runner there, but the source code files are not analized. I get in the sonar server update of the project, but it contains nothing, as seen here:

[image: sonarqube project page]

By the way, sometimes I get this, but it doesn't happen every time :

```
/opt/example$ sonar-runner scan
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.7.0_95 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64 amd64
INFO: Runner configuration file: /opt/sonar-runner/conf/sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: /opt/example/sonar-project.properties
INFO: Default locale: "de_DE", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: /opt/example/./.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.4
19:32:05.625 INFO  - Load global repositories
19:32:05.751 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=125ms
19:32:05.770 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.url' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
19:32:05.771 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.username' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
19:32:05.771 WARN  - Property 'sonar.jdbc.password' is not supported any more. It will be ignored. There is no longer any DB connection to the SQ database.
19:32:05.772 INFO  - User cache: /home/dettinstall/.sonar/cache
19:32:05.966 INFO  - Load plugins index
19:32:05.969 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=3ms
19:32:06.542 INFO  - Process project properties
19:32:06.666 INFO  - Load project repositories
19:32:06.736 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=70ms
19:32:06.751 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
19:32:06.828 INFO  - Load quality profiles
19:32:06.853 INFO  - Load quality profiles (done) | time=25ms
19:32:06.856 INFO  - Load active rules
19:32:07.470 INFO  - Load active rules (done) | time=614ms
19:32:07.476 WARN  - SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
19:32:07.476 INFO  - Publish mode
19:32:07.477 INFO  - -------------  Scan C++ :: Simple Project :: SonarQube Scanner
19:32:07.587 INFO  - Load server rules
19:32:07.676 INFO  - Load server rules (done) | time=89ms
19:32:07.747 INFO  - Base dir: /opt/example
19:32:07.748 INFO  - Working dir: /opt/example/.sonar
19:32:07.749 INFO  - Source paths: src
19:32:07.749 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: de_DE
19:32:07.749 INFO  - Index files
19:32:07.771 INFO  - 1 files indexed
19:32:07.776 INFO  - Quality profile for c: Sonar way
19:32:08.472 INFO  - JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : /opt/example/target/jacoco.exec
19:32:08.473 INFO  - JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: /opt/example/target/jacoco-it.exec
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 3.514s
Final Memory: 10M/120M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: No license for cpp
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Do I need some special licence?

Answer (score 1):

You do need a license for this plugin. You can [request an evaluation license](http://www.sonarsource.com/get-contact-sf/?Product__c=C/C%2B%2B&Request_Type__c=Request%20an%20evaluation%20license%20key).

It's quite surprising that you don't get the license error every time. Some of your analyses must not include C/C++ files.

Comment: I may misunderstood something, but isnt't sonarqube and the c++ plugin an open source software? For which c++ plugin I don't need a licence?

Comment: The SonarQube platform is FOSS, but the SonarSource C/C++ plugin is not. There is a community-supported plugin as well but I have no experience with it: https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx

Comment: those examples are c++ files (source+headers)